# When using loadData/loadUpdateData, how can I find a foreign key in another table based on data in the .csv file?

Tags: liquibase

Using liquibase and trying to automatically import translation data from an external Localization Database.  My CSV data is as follows:

ResourceBundle   StringName   Translation
base-enUS        baseString   This is a base string

I have a Resource Bundle table that looks as such:

```
ID (uuid)   Name
<uuid-id>   base-enUS
```

And I have a Resource table that looks like this:

```
ID(uuid)    Resource_Bundle_ID    StringName    StringValue
<uuid-id>   <ref to ResBundle>    baseString    This is a String Value
```

The "Resource Bundle" rows will have been manually inserted via Liquibase by this point in the changeset, so I can't hardcode foreign Key id's.

Is there a way I can do a look up of the ID of Resource_Bundle by the supplied Resource Bundle name in the middle of a liquibase loadUpdateData tag?

Comment: how often you want to load this data, is it one time execution?

Comment: Ideally we'd want to incorporate this into a build or deployment into a new environment.  So not regularly, but definitely once a release cycle (3-4 months).